# RxJava flow: conditional operators and error handling

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I'm a newbie to RxJava and try to wrap my head around a more complex login logic that has three async methods to process. For me this is "if I get this thing converted to RxJava, anything ([tm](http://zombo.com)) is possible" :)

So what I want to do is the following:

```
Call A -> (Process A) -> Call B with results of A -> (Process B) -\
                    \                                              -> Combine and Subscribe
                     \-> Call C with results of A -> (Process C) -/
```

Now the problem is that the `Call C` branch should only be executed on a specific condition, not otherwise (`Combine and Subscribe` could then receive a `NULL` value from that branch, this is ok).

Also, the error handling is non-trivial: While `Call A` and `Call C` (if this runs at all) need to deliver their errors via `onError` to the final subscriber, `Call B`'s "success" is rather optional and can be neglected in case of failure.

This is what I came up with so far, which ignores the "C" branch still:

```
 mApi.callA(someArgs)
            // a transition operator to apply thread schedulers
            .compose(applySchedulers())
            // from rxlifecycle-components, unsubscribes automatically 
            // when the activity goes down  
            .compose(bindToLifecycle())
            // possibly other transformations that should work on the (error)
            // states of the first and the following, chained API calls
            .flatMap(response -> processA(response))
            .flatMap(response -> mApi.callB(response.token))
            .flatMap(response -> processB(response))
            // redirects HTTP responses >= 300 to onError()
            .lift(new SequenceOperators.HttpErrorOperator<>())
            // checks for application-specific error payload and redirects that to onError()
            .lift(new SequenceOperators.ApiErrorOperator<>())
            .subscribe(this::allDone this::failure);
```

I looked around at the [Wiki for conditional operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Conditional-and-Boolean-Operators), but I cannot find a hint how to kick-off the `Call C` branch.

Also, I'm unsure if my `SequenceOperators` work out this way, i.e. can be put after all requests in the chain, or whether I need several of those, each placed intermediately after a flatMap() operator that triggers a new `Call`.

Could anybody point me into the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [Zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator :) the result should look like this:

```
mApi.callA(someArgs)
        // ...
        .flatMap(response -> processA(response))
        .flatMap(response -> {
              return Observable.zip(
                    callB(response),
                    callC(response),
                    (rA,rB) -> {
                          // or just return a new Pair<>(rA, rB)
                          return combineAPlusB(rA,rB)
                    }
              )
        })
        // ...
        .subscribe(this::allDone this::failure);
```

Comment: Ok, understood, now where I'm unsure is how I can do the error handling then. I'd like to have some operator / component / whatever that I throw in there and that acts generically on any response (hence the `HttpErrorOperator` and `ApiErrorOperator`). Also, you said on G+, the transition operators should go last (i.e. `compose`) - I think I have to take care of the "temperature" here, not that I accidentially make a "cold" observable a "hot" one, right?

Comment: if both callB and callC needs that, the easy solution would be to call .lift on both of them.

Comment: Otherwise, if both callB and callC emits the same type, you could Observable.merge(callB, callC).lift(..).toList().map(rarb -> combineAplusB(rarb.get(0), rarb.get(1));

Comment: Ok, I see. Unfortunately, they emit different (generic) types, so merging will not work. Many thanks for your help!